# Get text inside <head> tags with ruby during a Net::HTTP::Session

Tags: ruby, net-http

How do I get the text inside the

```
<head> ... </head>
```

tags from a web page using ruby during a Net::HTTP::Session?

```
Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).start(url) { |http|

id.upto(Max_ID) do |i| 
    t = http.head(request<<i.to_s).HEAD_TAGS# I want to get text inside <head></head>
    match_ch_names_for_id(t,i) unless !t        
end

}
```

I know I can get the source with

```
Net::Http.get(url, request)
```

but I need to do this many times and the script will be extremely slow if I keep reobtaining the connection. 
If I use the body or read_body methods for a Net::Http::Response object it won't return what's inside the head tags.

Comment: You're confused about what a HEAD request is. It's not a request for the head section of a html page, but rather the http headers that would normally get sent for a GET request.

Comment: What? I actually need the text data that's inside of the <head></head> tags. I'm not trying to get the header.

Comment: Right, I understand that. For that you need to make a GET request.